# Find a starting value such that the value of the function is always positive

Tags: summation

Suppose I have a variable number of integers, each of which can be of any value from negative to positive infinity, and not sorted in any particular order. For example:

```
-1, -1, -1, -2, 9
```

The "function" is evaluated by picking a starting point, and adding all the numbers up. For example, if I started with 3:

```
 3 - 1 =  2
 2 - 1 =  1
 1 - 1 =  0
 0 - 2 = -2 --> Negative
-2 + 9 =  7
```

There are periods where the sum is non-positive. However, if I started with 6:

```
6 - 1 =  5
5 - 1 =  4
4 - 1 =  3
3 - 2 =  1
1 + 9 = 10
```

Then at no point during the addition process is the sum non-positive.

Is there an formula or algorithm to efficiently determine the minimum starting value such that the partial sums are always positive?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you started with $3$, the most non-positive number you got was $-2$. So if you start with $3+3=6$, you won't get any number smaller than $3+-2=1$. This technique will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum starting value needed to make all partial sums positive is $1$ minus the minimum value reached when summing starting from $0$. As the numbers are arbitrary, the naive method is the most efficient one: sum starting from $0$, note the minimum value reached during the entire operation, negate and add $1$. The result is the optimal starting value.

Comment: What about the following set: `1 2 -3 4 -5`? There are no negative partial sums, but there is a zero, which is also not allowed. Negating and adding 1 results in 1, whereas the correct solution is 2.

Comment: @404NameNotFound The sequence you proposed has a final sum of $-1$ if starting from $0$.

Comment: Ah right. Thank you!